# Spring3, Hibernate; how do I use HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to change the following code to use: HibernateTemplate but cant it working

```
public List<Friend> listFriends(String rUser) 
{
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

    Friend friend = new Friend();
        friend.setUsername(rUser);

    // This is the old code that worked!
            return (List<Friend>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Friend.class)
            .add(Example.create(friend))
            .list();

        // This IS THE NEW CODE THAT I CANT GET TO BUILD?
            return (List<Friend>) hibernateTemplate.createCriteria(Friend.class)
            .add(Example.create(friend))
            .list();
}
```

Comment: if you are having a compiler error, post the output from the compiler.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setUsername(rUser);

return (List<Friend>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(
        DetachedCriteria.forClass(Friend.class)
        .add(Example.create(friend)));
```

or

```
Friend friend = new Friend();
    friend.setUsername(rUser);

return (List<Friend>) hibernateTemplate.findByExample(friend);
```

or

```
return (List<Friend>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(
        DetachedCriteria.forClass(Friend.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("username", rUser)));
```

Answer (score 1):

`HibernateTemplate` doesn't provide `createCriteria()` method. I guess you need this:

```
return (List<Friend>) hibernateTemplate.findByExample(friend);
```

**See also:**

- [`HibernateTemplate` javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all have your DAO class extends HIbernateDAOSupport so that you have the getHibernateTemplate() method.

Then use:

```
getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
    Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
        return session.createCriteria(Friend.class)
        .add(Example.create(friend))
        .list();
    }
});
```

The template is created when you call setSessionFactory() on your DAO class (add it as a spring dependency to be injected).

The template will then call the doInHibernate() of the supplied callback, passing in the session (which it will obtain from the session factory)

Answer (score 1):

my advise is exdens `HibernateDaoSupport` and inject `hibernateTemplate` or `sessionFactory` from the xml so you will get protected methods to your DAOImpl class so you can get `hibernateTemplate` like this `getHibernateTemplate()` and criteria method you can call like this `getSession().createCriteria();`

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize sessionFactory? If you initialize sessionFactory correctly, so make your class, which conatians the above method, extends HibernateDAOSupport class which have getHibernateTemplate()  method.